# can i set hotkey action in PhpStorm depending on file extension?

Tags: phpstorm

For example: I need hotkey (Ctrl+Shift+F) for reformatting code in php files and same hotkey for use external tool in css files.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @LazyOne, this is currently not possible in the latest version (8.0.1).